# Assembly Language Basics

Tags: assembly

I'm learning assembly language and I am not doing well. I can't find much about it on google, so I gently ask you guys to help me out with that.

I have a test next week and I'm trying to study for it, but as I said, I can't find what I really need about assembly language on google. Here are some questions that might come up on my exam:

I would like just a quick answer for them, just to have a notion, if that is ok. Thank you so much for the help!:

1. Registers are pushed onto the stack but are popped in reverse order. Explain why this is the case.
2. A typical procedure definition includes the backup and restoration of registers. Explain why     this is necessary
3. Register to register moves, eg. 'MOV AL, BL' are not supported in the SMZ simulator as used in
   classes. In view of this limitation, explain how the contents of the BL register can be copied to AL.
4. Explain the connection between the “cmp” instruction and conditional jump instructions   such as “jz”.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you try the course material, professors notes, previous assignments, and the text books for your course?

Comment: Yes, I did. All the course material I have is from Moodle, which doesn't talk about these kind of questions, only about Kernel, OS, etc. I dont have books for this course, it is all from Moodle.

Comment: Well an analogy for question 1 is. A stack works like a pile of dinner plates. You put one plate on top of another. The bottom of the stack is the first plate, and top of the stack is the last plate you put on. The very first plate on the bottom is now covered by all the other plates. To get to the first plate (or any earlier plate) you remove the plates in reverse order. This is considered Last In First Out, and a stack is an example.

Comment: Saving and restoring registers is dependent on _Calling Convention_ . If a calling convention says that particular registers (or all of them) are saved by the callee (the function itself) then it is up to the function to save and restore them. Often this is done by pushing the original values on the stack at start and popping them off at the end to restore them.

Comment: If you can't do register to register then do register to memory. Use a memory location that can hold a byte and copy _BL_ to it with `mov`. Then use a `mov` instruction to move from that memory location into _AL_.

Comment: CMP sets the processor flags (condition codes) based on the result of SUB Destination, Source (Destination minus source) without actually saving the result in the destination. the Jcc (like _JZ_) test the flags.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That's how stack works, you always look on the top item, so if you insert the item x and then y, y is on top, so when you pop the argument, you pop first y and then x. You can write custom assembly code that pops the argument as you entered them, but that's not really logical for stack.
2. You don't always know the code in the called procedure, and it may change the registers values, so you save them before, so no matter what the called procedure will do, when it returns, the registers state will be the same as you left it
3. Not sure, Don't know that simulator...
4. This how assembly implements things like if statements. You jump to specific code if the statement is true, and somewhere else (or not jump) if not. For example, `if(a == b)` when EAX is holding the value of a and EBX is holding the value of b, the assembly code will subtract the values (cmp subtract the registers and save the result in the flag registers), and if it zero, it jumps to the code inside the if, and if not, continue or jump to the else statement

Hope I helped, sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: It did, bro. Thank you so much!

Comment: Mark answer as useful if so :) Good luck in the exam! @LucasBecker